# how spring security works

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

**Purpose** of my question is to **understand** and get clear picture of how Security /Session work in Spring . As i am quiet new to Spring concepts.
i followed this tutorial to understand

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

My aim is : when user requests for some resource (for eg. /order/details) and if that request has no token in header then it should be redirected to login page with new token .

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request
                        .getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                        response.sendRedirect("/login");
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

the above code works fine but regarding redirecting to login page,i am not able to achieve it.

Please help me in understanding the concept here . if you need any more details please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Tell me that. I have worked quite some time in this!!

Comment: I am updating my code please see this

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, Spring-Security already has mechanism in place to do that. You are making it complicated is what I can say. Refer to the guide and do a configuration. Also, please try to explain properly what is the problem. I already lost what is going on from 3rd paragraph itself.

Comment: @We are Borg please check it now...i have updated my post to make it more explainatory.

Answer (score 0):

I was in your place couple of weeks back. I had to integrate security into a spring project and I was new to both spring and security.
Here is what I did.

1. Browsed through quite a few security frameworks
2. Learned a little bit about what are identity module authentication module etc.
3. I came across [KeyCloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/). I worked with its version 1.4
4. Installed the keycloak locally and set up the realm
5. Configured my springboot app with keycloak adapters (you can find all about it in keycloak documentation)
6. And that was it. I was able to secure my web app and rest api using just a json file and one xml configuration file.

Have a look at it.
I am not an expert at either security or spring. Just sharing the recent work that I have done.